# Set batch break points in .NET Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

I got a new demo project I want to study today. I want to hit debug and follow the process and see the sequence of the function calls and follow its logic. I actually had this idea in my mind for quite a few times already.

I wonder when I get a new project, if it is possible to batch process break points at each function of each class? I am not talking about hitting F11 line by line, I want the break points to be at the header of each of the functions, so I can quickly scheme through each functions.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: You could probably write a macro to do that.

Comment: How? A few lines of code or some keywords to get me started please? If I figured out a solution, I really want to post it back here. I am sure many developers are interested in it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967.aspx